# Os dados não são inseridos no banco de dados usando PDO

Tags: php, pdo

To com um problema, basicamente os dados não estão sendo inseridos no banco de dados, e não está apresentando erro, ainda sou iniciante, e não consigo entender aonde está o erro:

Script:

```
 require_once ('config.php');



    $idAnime = 5025;
    while($idAnime < 8000)
    {


        $verificaAnime = $crud->select('idMal','animesmal','WHERE idMal = ?')->run([$idAnime]);
        $contaRow = $verificaAnime->rowCount();

        if($contaRow == 0)
        {

            $text = $apiMal->get_busca($idAnime);



            if(is_array($text))
            {

                $title = $text['title'];
                $id = $text['idAnime'];
                $score = $text['score'];
                $desc = $text['description'];
                $desc = $translate->runTranslate($desc);

                $dados = array($id,$title,$desc);

                $certo = $crud->insert('animesMal','idMAl = ?, name = ?, description = ?, score = ?')
                ->run(array($id,$title,$desc, $score));

                if($certo)
                {
                    echo 'sucesso ao Adicionar o anime '.'<span class="msg-sucesso">'.$title.'</span>'.' ao banco de dados.<br>';
                }else
                {
                    echo 'Erro ao inserir animes no banco de dados<br>Erro:  '.$certo;
                }


            }else
            {
                echo '<span class="msg-erro">'.$text.'</span><br>';
            }
        }else
        {
            echo '<span class="msg-erro">'."ERRO: O anime já existe no banco de dados</span><br>";            // echo var_dump($verificaAnime);
        }
    $idAnime++;
    }
```

CRUD:::

```
    <?php

 namespace Classes;

class Crud{

    private $query, $run;


    public function __construct()
    {
        openDatabase();
    }

    private function set_statement($s)
    {
        if(openDatabase()){

            $this->query = openDatabase()->prepare($s);

        } else{
            die(closeDatabase($conn));
        }
    }

    // Execulta
    private function do_run()
    {

        $this->query->execute($this->run);
    }

    public function run($r = [])
    {
        $this->run = $r;
        $this->do_run();

        return $this->query;
    }

    // Funçao que insert dados no banco de dados
    public final function insert($table, $values)
    {

        $this->set_statement('INSERT INTO '.$table.' SET '.$values.'');
        return $this;
    }

    public final function select($fields, $table, $condition = '')
    {

        $this->set_statement('SELECT ' .$fields.' FROM '.$table.' '.$condition);
        return $this;
    }

    public final function update($table, $values,$condition)
    {
        'UPDATE $tabela SET mail = ? WHERE id = ?';
        $this->set_statement();
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Como está a sua função insert?

Comment: pera ai vô adicionar meu crud

Comment: Seu insert não está correto. O modo como você escreveu o `insert` serve para a função `update`

Comment: como assim? esse é o erro?

Comment: Tenta os `=` e deixar só os   campos

Comment: Inves de mandar assim: `insert('animesMal','idMAl = ?, name = ?, description = ?, score = ?')` manda assim `insert('animesMal','idMAl, name, description, score')`

Comment: Eu tentei e continua não funcionando, e não exibe nenhum erro

Comment: Antes de ` if($certo)` coloca isso ` print_r($certo->errorInfo()); exit;`

Comment: ele tinha retornado um erro de por ter removido os = ?, depois que os coloquei de volta ele so retorna Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )

Comment: Na posição 1 do array mostra que mensagem?

Comment: Para uma exibição melhor você colocar assim: `echo "<pre>"; print_r($certo->errorInfo()); echo "</pre>"; exit;`

Comment: Então, hj rodei o code do jeito que está nesse post e tudo funcionou perfeitamente kk. Agora eu to muito perdido. PQ não faço ideia do que aconteceu e nem como voltou a funcionar kk

Comment: Estranho, porque a sintaxe do insert é `INSERT INTO tabela (campo1, campo2, campo3) VALUES ()` e não `INSERT INTO tabela  SET campo1 = 1, campo2 = 2`

Comment: pse kk, Vlw pela ajuda